# Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular5

I'm learning `Angular5` and how to use `useFactory` with `deps`.
Currently in my `Angular` app I have **one component** and **three services.**

Here is the component

```
// email.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  ...
})
export class EmailComponent implements OnInit {
  private currentEmail: string;
  private companyName: string;

  constructor(@Inject('EMS') private emailService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.currentEmail = this.emailService.emailServiceName;
  }
}
```

and the template is

```
// email.component.html
<p>Your Current Email Service is : {{ currentEmail }}</p>
```

and here is the `app.module.ts`:

```
...
import { EmailComponent } from './components/email/email.component';
import { EmailService } from './email-service';
import { HotMail } from './hot-mail';
import { YahooMail } from './yahoo-mail';


function HotMailOrYahooMail(x) {
  if (x.isHotMail) {
    return new HotMail();
  } else {
    return new YahooMail();
  }
}
@NgModule({
  ...
  providers: [
    EmailService,
    {
      provide: 'EMS',
      useFactory: HotMailOrYahooMail,
      deps: [EmailService]
    }
  ],
  ...
})
export class AppModule { }
```

The **logic** is that `EmailComponent` should render **value returned either** from `HotMail` service or `YahooMail` service, and **this logic is located on** `EmailService`, i.e `EmailService` has a property called `isHotMail`, **if its value is true** then `'EMS'` should point towards `HotMail` service, **otherwise** it should point towards `YahooMail` service.

Here is `EmailService`

```
export class EmailService {
    constructor(public isHotMail: boolean) {
        this.isHotMail = true;
    }
}
```

and `HotMail` service:

```
export class HotMail {
  public emailServiceName = 'HotMail by Microsoft';
}
```

and `YahooMail` service:

```
export class YahooMail {
  public emailServiceName = 'YahooMail by Yahoo';
}
```

**However,** when running `ng serve`, I got following error:

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for EmailService: (?).
        at syntaxError (compiler.js:485)
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getDependenciesMetadata (compiler.js:15699)
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getTypeMetadata (compiler.js:15534)
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getInjectableMetadata (compiler.js:15514)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getProviderMetadata (compiler.js:15874)
        at eval (compiler.js:15785)
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at CompileMetadataResolver._getProvidersMetadata (compiler.js:15745)
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (compiler.js:15313)
        at JitCompiler._loadModules (compiler.js:34404)
```

What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

My bad, I should've use this

```
export class EmailService {
    public isHotMail = true;
}
```